# Possible to eliminate this sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a documents table with say fields as

```
DocumentID int - PK and autoincrement 
LastStatusChangedDateTime - datetime 
JurisdictionID - int 
DocumentStatusID - int
```

now I want to bring in a computed column named `CanChangeStatus`. This is like a queue. So if the document is first in it's status can be changed. This is my query:

```
Select d.DocumentID,  
(
    Select Cast(Case When d.DocumentID = v.DocumentID Then 1 Else 0 End as bit)
    From
    (
        Select Top 1 DocumentID
        From Documents
        Where JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
            And
        DocumentStatusID = d.DocumentStatusID
        Order By LastStatusChangedDateTime 
    ) v
) as CanChangeStatus    
From Documents d
```

Index is there on `JurisdictionID` and `DocumentStatusID`. The culprit is the subquery - the way I am trying to calculate `CanChangeStatus`. Is there any way I can speed this up or convert this subquery into join because joins are *mostly* faster than subqueries?

Comment: Does this really need to be done in SQL or could that's processing this return perform the action? It eliminates your subquery and the join and puts the logic into the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an aggregate function (example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca3c9/4)):

```
SELECT DocumentID,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY JurisdictionID, DocumentStatusID
                                     ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime )
         = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Bit 
FROM Documents
```

Comment: I am stunned! My query took 5 seconds with subquery and now it takes between 300 to 500 ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Cast(Case When TOP_DocumentID = DocumentID Then 1 Else 0 End as bit), DOCUMENTID
FROM
(
Select TOP 1 DOCUMENT_ID TOP_DocumentID, D.DOCUMENTID
From Documents d, DOCUMENTS J
Where J.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
And J.DocumentStatusID = d.DocumentStatusID
Order By J.LastStatusChangedDateTime 
) A
```